# Arquivo .reg ou .txt no windows

Tags: php

Como posso em PHP criar um arquivo .reg ou .txt em um local por ex. ( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ) e inserir dentro dele o valor de duas variáveis string  $minhaVarReg01 e $minhaVarReg02 .

E posteriormente abrir esse mesmo arquivo via PHP também e comparar os valores dentro desse arquivo com uma outras variáveis string  $minhaVarComparaReg01  e  $minhaVarComparaReg01 .

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não o poderá fazer atravez de PHP. Tente VBScript.

**Ideia:**

- O VBScript irá criar uma tarefa (caso esta nao exista) no "Task Scheduler" que executará o mesmo de X em X (horas/minutos/segundos)
- No mesmo ficheiro será feito um **HTTPRequest** com o seu serviço.

  - Caso seja a primeira vez que o corre este request retornará os valores a serem inseridos no Registry ou respectivo ficheiro .txt.
  - Caso contrário neste request serão passados os dados do Registry ou .txt, que serão tratados depois em php.

Encontrei abaixo uma versao muito basica:

> Nota: Este código não foi testado.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."

Function post(url, data)
    'Faz o request para o servidor com parametros POST e retorna a resposta
    Dim restReq
    Set restReq = CreateObject ("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
    restReq.open "POST", url, False
    restReq.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    restReq.send(data)
    post = restReq.responseText
End Function

Function cwrite(path, filename, data)
    'Escreve um ficheiro numa determinada pasta, caso nao exista a pasta ou o ficheiro cria os dois
    Dim objFile, file
    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    file = path & filename
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(path) = True Then  objFSO.CreateFolder path
    If objFSO.FileExists(file) = True Then objFSO.deletefile file, True
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(file,True)
    objFile.Write data
    objFile.Close
End Function

Function existsFile(file)
    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    existsFile = objFSO.FileExists(file)
End Function

Function MakeTask(schedule, modifier, title, action)
    'Cria uma tarefa usando SchTasks 
    Set wShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    wShell.Run "SchTasks /Create /SC " & schedule & " /MO " & modifier & " /TN """ & title & """ /TR """ & action & """ /F", 0
End Function

Function getRegistryValue(strKeyPath, strValueName)
    'Busca o valor de um determinado registo
    Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,regValue
    Set oReg = Nothing
    If Not regValue = 0 Then
        getRegistryValue = regValue
    Else
        getRegistryValue = Nothing
    End If
End Function

'###
'INICIO DA APLICAÇÃO

Set wShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Sys_Drive = wShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")
SERVICE_URL = "http://url_do_serviço.com/serviço.php"
FILE_PATH = Sys_Drive & "\"

If Not existsFile(FILE_PATH & "ficheiro.txt") Then
    'EFECTUA O REQUEST PARA O SERVIÇO
    responseBody = post(SERVICE_URL, "data1=value1&data2=value2")
    'ESCREVE O FICHEIRO "ficheiro.txt" COM O VALOR "responseBody"
    cwrite FILE_PATH, "ficheiro.txt", responseBody
    ' CRIA A TAREFA PARA SER EXECUTADA DE 15 EM 15 MINUTOS MakeTask([HOURLY|MINUTE|SECOND], [NUMERIC], [TITULO], [AÇAO])
    MakeTask "MINUTE", 15, "A MINHA TAREFA", "caminho_para_o_ficheiro_vbs/ping.vbs"

Else
    'CASO O FICHEIRO EXISTA ....
End If
```

**NÃO EXECUTE O CODIGO ACIMA AQUI POIS ESTE É VBSCRIPT**

Comment: OK, porem esse arquivo ficará separado junto com meus demais arquivos .php, isso ?  qual a extensão para salvar este arquivo ?  e como chamar esse procedimento no PHP passando os parâmetros  para guardar e verificar depois ?

Comment: Gostei dessa ideia, porem nunca apliquei,  preciso de ajuda para aplica-la aqui na prática.

Comment: como posso fazer  ?

Comment: Alguém conhece uma solução ,  pois ainda nada,  ?

Comment: Articuno & Gonsalo Souza   /   Ainda nada por aqui ,  não consegui resolver essa pergunta.  Será melhor abrir outra pergunta  ?

Comment: @PauloMaia Primeiro passo a desculpar-me por nao ter explicado essa parte, esse arquivo terá que ser guardado com extenção `vbs`. Segundo reparei que abriu outra pergunta, o problema foi resolvido? Vi tambem que está usando apenas **PHP** como sugerido na resposta que obteve, porem não podera fazer quaisquer mudanças num arquivo que esteja guardado num local na maquina **Desktop** por exemplo. Se necessitar mais informação poderei pois postar uma versão completa que o ajudará a conseguir o requisitado.

Comment: ,   Ainda estou sem solução  !

Comment: @PauloMaia Apenas mais uns detalhes antes de criar uma versão estavel para o requisitado, 1 - Necessita executar em maquinas cliente ou apenas na sua maquina local? (caso cliente: o mesmo terá que correr o arquivo `vbs` apenas uma vez). 2 - Que tipo de dados serão guardados apenas texto ou binario/hexadecimal? 3 - Terá que salvar esta informação no Registry ou poderá ser num arquivo `txt` num local especifico?

Comment: ,  Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226338/como-escrever-e-ler-dados-do-registro-do-windows-com-php/226371#226371  e tambem https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226381/como-manipular-a-string-vinda-de-um-arquivo-reg-exportado-do-regedit#226385

Comment: ------>  * Tenho um sistema de login que recebe dados de um webservice, porem ao usuario acessar o login estando ele sem estar conectado a internet, não é possível acessar o webservice em questão, por esse motivo pretendo guardar em um arquivo externo por ex. no registro do windows dessa mesma maquina onde o sistema de login esta instalado PHP, guardar o valor de 2 variáveis uma é o numero de serial do sistema que libera a entrada ao sistema através do login e outra é um numero que pode variar de 0-99 .......... continuo no prox. comentário  .....

Comment: que é um numero de segurança que disponibilizo para o caso do usuário ficar sem internet por um tempo o sistema ir descontando dessa cota disponibilizada para acessos off e ir decrescendo esse numero no registro até chegar um ponto em que ele não tem saída pois acabaram-se as cotas de execuções em off e ele tem obrigatoriamente que fazer o login conectado para que o sistema atualize os dados salvos no registro do windows

Comment: Preciso da Rotina Completa php , Eu não tenho o .reg ele precisa ser criado via rotina php e escrito/guardado nele o valor de 2 variaveis e depois em outra rotina buscar ele e comparar os valores guardados nele com as ontras 2 variaveis locais para ver se são valores iguais...................   Será rodado no cliente  /  Dados String Textos / Acredito que no Registro do Windows é mais seguro pois não se perde e fica bem guardado  /  Pode ser um Txt sim.

Comment: @PauloMaia Percebi perfeitamente a ideia, contudo como expliquei acima o cliente terá que executar o ficheiro `vbs` que irá criar uma tarefa que funcionará como **"socket"** requisitando o seu serviço de X em X tempo, Outra solução será utilizar **cookies** ou o proprio **LocalStorage** do browser em **javascript**. Será o cliente capaz de executar o tal ficheiro? e como pensa distribuir o mesmo? O **PHP** não tem qualquer acesso á maquina local, isto porque ele corre apenas no servidor, o javascript tambem é incapaz de realizar açoes fora do browser.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63295/discussion-between-gonsalo-sousa-and-paulomaia).

Comment: Conseguiu algum resultado no Código Adaptado ?