# Como escrever e ler dados do registro do windows com php?

Tags: php

Preciso escrever e ler dados no registro do windows com php , como fazer ?

Comment: Não entendi os votos negativos - é uma boa pergunta.

Comment: OK `Para ler, vc faz o reg export. Algo assim: reg export Hkey_local_Machine\Software\blabla C:\export.txt. Isso gera um txt e então vc faz a leitura do txt com o php e abstrai o que precisa`  ,,,,, 

Para ler uso esse procedimento  `<?php  reg export Hkey_local_Machine\Software\blabla C:\export.txt ?>`    e criar ?

Comment: OK, `Daniel Omine`  ,  Aguardo Resposta !  Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado !    `Daniel Omine`   , Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para escrever no registro do Windows, execute o comando `reg import`

```
<?php
exec('reg import c:\arquivo.reg');
```

Para ler um registro do Windows, execute o comando `reg export`

```
<?php
// Exporta o registro para um arquivo texto
exec('reg export Hkey_local_Machine\Software\blabla C:\arquivo.reg');

// Em seguida, faz a leitura desse arquivo
$registro = file_get_contents('C:\arquivo.reg');

// Agora você trabalha com funções de manipulação de string para abstrair o que necessita da variável `$registro`.
```

O arquivo "arquivo.reg" vai ter algo assim

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\leroLero]
"parametro1"=valor
"parametro2"=valor
"parametro3"=valor
```

Então você abstrai o que interessa que é os parâmetros e os respectivos valores.

*Como manipular a string é outro assunto. Você pode fazer uma nova pergunta para evitar tornar o tópico "amplo demais", o que é motivo para fechamento.

Tópico interessante (SO-en): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579195

Comment: Obrigado !    `Daniel Omine`   , Muito Obrigado.   `Vou adaptar aqui e também vou ler o Tópico` .

Comment: Abro então um tópico agora para =>  *Como manipular a string  ?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226381/como-manipular-a-string

Comment: só mais uma dúvida  em que ponto estou carregando o valor das minhas variáveis dentro do arquivo ?  aqui  =>  `$registro = file_get_contents('C:\arquivo.reg');`   ?

Comment: @daniel ate que ponto essa solução funcionará com **PHP** caso esteja usando um servidor com base `Linux`? e se quiser executa-lo no cliente e não no servidor? (Interesse Puro) pois tenho usado uma aproximação com **vbscript** para correr comandos em maquinas cliente

Comment: O Linux não possui um "regedit" como no Windows. A estrutura e ferramentas são diferentes. Se for fazer para Linux bastaria salvar em arquivos texto em locais privados onde o usuário não teria acesso. Aliás, isso também poderia ser aplicado aqui mas o AP exige que seja feito no registro do Windows. É uma questão de opinião. A lógica é a mesma, só muda os recursos. @GonsaloSousa